# HTTPService AsyncToken and AsyncResponder example

Tags: apache-flex, asynchronous, httpresponse, httpservice, asynctoken

Where can I find an example of Flex application which implements an HTTPService asynchronously called by an AsyncToken and an AsyncResponder?
Thanks in advance

the httpservice send a string like this with a certain frequency:

row#column#number#row#column#number#row#column#number#....

EDITED CODE:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<mx:Application creationComplete="onCreationComplete()" 
xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml" layout="absolute">
<mx:Script>
<![CDATA[
    import mx.rpc.remoting.RemoteObject;
    import mx.rpc.events.ResultEvent;
    import mx.rpc.events.FaultEvent;
    import mx.rpc.http.mxml.HTTPService;
    import mx.rpc.AsyncRequest;
    import mx.rpc.AsyncResponder;
    import mx.rpc.AsyncToken;
    import mx.collections.ArrayCollection;
    import mx.controls.advancedDataGridClasses.AdvancedDataGridColumn;
    import mx.controls.AdvancedDataGrid;
    import mx.controls.Alert;
    import mx.rpc.IResponder;


    [Bindable]
    public var dataList:ArrayCollection;

    public function getResults(source:String) : ArrayCollection {
    var ac:ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection();
    var data:Array = source.split('#');
    for (var i:int = 0; i < data.length; i += 3) {
    var dataObj:Object = {row: data[i], column: data[i+1], value: data[i+2]};     
    ac.addItem(dataObj)
    }

    return ac;
    }
    public function result(event:ResultEvent):void{
    dataList = getResults( String(event.result) );
    }
    public function fault(event:FaultEvent) : void {
    dataList = getResults(String(event.fault)); 
    }

public function onCreationComplete():void
{
var service:HTTPService = new HTTPService();
service.url = "http://10.15.20.75/server4flex/servlet/Datagen";
service.resultFormat = "text";
var token:AsyncToken = service.send(dataList);
token.addResponder(new mx.rpc.Responder(result, fault));
}

]]>
</mx:Script>
<mx:AdvancedDataGrid id="dg"
dataProvider="{result}"  
liveScrolling="true"  
    x="10" y="10" width="621"
    verticalScrollPolicy="on"
 >
        <mx:columns>
                    <mx:AdvancedDataGridColumn dataField="row"
           headerText="Riga"/>
                    <mx:AdvancedDataGridColumn dataField="column"
           headerText="Colonna"/>
                    <mx:AdvancedDataGridColumn dataField="value" 
           headerText="Valore"/>
        </mx:columns>
 </mx:AdvancedDataGrid>

 </mx:Application>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I dont know what you are really looking after but [here](http://www.flexafterdark.com/docs/ActionScript-Responder) or [here](http://www.flexafterdark.com/docs/Flex-HttpService) for example, are way to use `AsyncToken` and `AsyncResponder`

**Edit:**

1. your `dataList` have to be `Bindable`
2. Don't set `dataList` on each loop iteration
3. You have to call you function `getResults` at some point when your results are ready
4. `event` in `result` function is an `Event` but also a `ResultEvent` where there is a `result` field containing your data

Which may look as this (untested):

```
[Bindable]
public var dataList:ArrayCollection;

public function getResults(source:String) : ArrayCollection {
    var ac:ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection();
    var data:Array = source.split('#');
    for (var i:int = 0; i < data.length; i += 3) {  
     ac.addItem( {row: data[i], column: data[i+1], value: data[i+2]} );
    }
    return ac;
}

private function result(event:ResultEvent) : void {
 dataList = getResults( String(event.result) );
}
```

**Edit2**:

this is a working example using a simple php file to get the data running on a local web server.

> Flex part

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<mx:Application creationComplete="onCreationComplete()"
            xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml" layout="absolute">
<mx:Script>
<![CDATA[
  import mx.collections.ArrayCollection;
  import mx.rpc.AsyncToken;
  import mx.rpc.Responder;
  import mx.rpc.events.FaultEvent;
  import mx.rpc.events.ResultEvent;
  import mx.rpc.http.mxml.HTTPService;

    [Bindable]
    public var dataList : ArrayCollection;

    public function getResults(source : String) : ArrayCollection {
        var ac : ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection();
        var data : Array = source.split('#');
        for (var i : int = 0; i < data.length; i += 3) {
            var dataObj : Object = {row: data[i], column: data[i + 1], value: data[i + 2]};
            ac.addItem(dataObj)
        }

        return ac;
    }

    public function result(event : ResultEvent) : void {
        dataList = getResults(String(event.result));
    }

    public function fault(event : FaultEvent) : void {
        //here do whatever you want to manage the error you received
    }

    public function onCreationComplete() : void
    {
        var service : HTTPService = new HTTPService();
        service.url = "http://127.0.0.1/getDatas.php";
        service.resultFormat = "text";
        var token : AsyncToken = service.send();
        token.addResponder(new mx.rpc.Responder(result, fault));
    }

]]>
</mx:Script>
<mx:AdvancedDataGrid id="dg"
                     dataProvider="{dataList}"
                     liveScrolling="true"
                     x="10" y="10" width="621"
                     verticalScrollPolicy="on"
        >
    <mx:columns>
        <mx:AdvancedDataGridColumn dataField="row"
                                   headerText="Riga"/>
        <mx:AdvancedDataGridColumn dataField="column"
                                   headerText="Colonna"/>
        <mx:AdvancedDataGridColumn dataField="value"
                                   headerText="Valore"/>
    </mx:columns>
</mx:AdvancedDataGrid>

</mx:Application>
```

> Php part (getDatas.php)

```
<?php print "1#c1#v1#2#c2#v2#3#c3#v3"?>
```

Comment: yes that's what I'm talking about, but I was looking for a sample application or source

Comment: Well i think you have all what you need in the two link above. What do you not understand ?

Comment: i edited the question...
the datagrid does not return anything if i use asyncToken and asyncResponder and I can't solve the problem.
My application works only if the string has a limited length, but i need something who retrieve data from an infinite string.

Comment: I edited my post with the last release of the application but it still doesn't work and I can't solve the problem

Comment: You are no more adding the result handler to the async token why ?

token.addResponder(new Responder(result, fault));

Comment: re-edited but still doesn't work, is it possible my application idea is not the right way?

Comment: See my last edit, i provide a tested and working example.

You are setting your dataProvider to {result} , it has to be {dataList}. In you fault handler you shouldn't do a getResults since an error occured you will surely not get the data you are expected.  Now since my example is working, are you sure you get the data from you server ? Don't you get a security error accessing data from one domain to another ? Etc...

Comment: it works!!!!
the only problem is that if i loop the php with a while or a for statement, the values come all toegether and not one by one at each request:



     <?php
     for($i=1;$i<100;i++)
     {
     echo rand(1,100)."#".rand(1,100)."#".rand(1,100)."#";
     }
     ?>

Answer (score 4):

```
private function onCreationComplete():void
{
    var service:HTTPService = new HTTPService();
    service.url = "http://www.google.com";
    service.resultFormat = "text";
    var token:AsyncToken = service.send();
    token.addResponder(new mx.rpc.Responder(result, fault));
}

private function result(event:Event):void
{
    trace(1, event);
}

private function fault(event:Event):void
{
    trace(2, event);
}
```

Found [here](http://bugs.adobe.com/jira/browse/SDK-22333).