# Pass an array collection in JSON

Tags: java, json, apache-flex

I am trying to pass an array collection from flex page to my backend java.Here is the code,

```
private function getItems():void{

                myObj  = new Object();
                myObj['dId']= dId.value.toString();
                myObj['itmList']=JSON.encode(itmList);// trying to pass like this..
                var url:String = URLManager.baseURL;
                    url = url+"myController/ReportController?do=getItems";
                    url = url+"&parameter="+ escape(JSON.encode(myObj))
                    var urlRequest:URLRequest = new URLRequest(url);
                    navigateToURL(urlRequest,"_blank");

               }
```

My `itmList` is an array collection, how can I pass it from JSon to Java controller? And how to get that in Java?

Comment: http://www.json.org/javadoc/org/json/JSONArray.html

Comment: From my earlier experience, do not just post the link. Think about the case where the link might be broken in future.

Please write some explanation and address the link for more info.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JSON.encode the itmList source array instead. (i.e. `itmList.source` is an array)

Then use HTTPService instead:
[HTTPService AsyncToken and AsyncResponder example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2040947/httpservice-asynctoken-and-asyncresponder-example)

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to use JSON.stringify instead (Flash has had native JSON support since FP 11).  Just make sure you remove the `import com.adobe.serialization.json.JSON;` from the top of your file.

`myObj['itmList']=JSON.stringify(itmList);`

Or, since you're encoding your whole data object,

```
myObj['itmList']=itmList.source;

var url:String = URLManager.baseURL;
                url = url+"myController/ReportController?do=getItems";
                url = url+"&parameter="+ escape(JSON.stringify(myObj))
                var urlRequest:URLRequest = new URLRequest(url);
                navigateToURL(urlRequest,"_blank");
```